# USB devices (flash drive, mouse) not recognised

Tags: 10.10, usb

I am using Ubuntu 10.10. When I mount a USB flash drive or mouse, my laptop does not recognise those devices. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to add more details to your question first.  Open a terminal and run `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`.  Then plug in your USB device and post the result of your terminal into your question.  Also what make/model is the device you're plugging in?

Comment: Please attach output of `dmesg`, `mount` command you are using and `mount` error message.

Comment: I've the same problem with usb devices on my laptop with 11.04 
`dmesg | grep -i usb` gives
`[   15.430049] ohci_hcd 0000:00:12.0: USB HC takeover failed!  (BIOS/SMM bug)`